# How to install HyperOpt-Sklearn library in Google Collab?

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, hyperopt

Every time I try to install HyperOpt-Sklearn library in Google Collab, I get the following error:

```
fatal: destination path 'hyperopt-sklearn' already exists and is not an empty directory.
/bin/bash: line 0: cd: hyperopt: No such file or directory
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found. Directory cannot be installed in editable mode: /content
```

Not sure why I get an error with this library and not with others.

I use the installation code that they suggest in their website:

```
!git clone https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-sklearn.git
!cd hyperopt
!pip install -e .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not mentioned in their documentation, turns out the package is available at [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/hpsklearn/) and it can be installed simply by `pip`; the following is run in a Google Colab notebook:

```
!pip install hpsklearn

Collecting hpsklearn
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ce/cb/61b99f73621e2692abd0e730f7888a9983d01f626868336fa1db1d57bc1e/hpsklearn-0.1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: hyperopt in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from hpsklearn) (0.1.2)
Collecting nose
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/d8/dd071918c040f50fa1cf80da16423af51ff8ce4a0f2399b7bf8de45ac3d9/nose-1.3.7-py3-none-any.whl (154kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 5.3MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from hpsklearn) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from hpsklearn) (0.22.2.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from hpsklearn) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from hyperopt->hpsklearn) (2.5)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from hyperopt->hpsklearn) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from hyperopt->hpsklearn) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from hyperopt->hpsklearn) (3.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from hyperopt->hpsklearn) (4.41.1)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn->hpsklearn) (0.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from networkx->hyperopt->hpsklearn) (4.4.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: hpsklearn
  Building wheel for hpsklearn (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for hpsklearn: filename=hpsklearn-0.1.0-cp36-none-any.whl size=23915 sha256=44744a68278f221b86c4e3e98ca5671bce66901893dfb93af1844e01dbc7b03f
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/41/ee/c4/3c267cbf78f0905434ee36b915d97a20610ad3af7ff3c75852
Successfully built hpsklearn
Installing collected packages: nose, hpsklearn
Successfully installed hpsklearn-0.1.0 nose-1.3.7
```